# Search Function that could search either using one or more values

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am trying to create a search function. But I have a difficulty on how to do it. I am new in symfony2 and just learning by myself and reading some tutorial.

I have here a search function in my DefaultController.

```
public function searchAction(){     
$request = $this->getRequest();
$data = $request->request->get('search');
$data1 = $request->request->get('search1');
$data2 = $request->request->get('search2');

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
 'SELECT p 
 FROM FooTransBundle:Transaction p, FooTransBundle:Supplier d
 WHERE p.transType LIKE :data
 AND d.name LIKE :data1
 AND p.sendDate LIKE :data2')
->setParameter('data',$data)
->setParameter('data1',$data1)
->setParameter('data2',$data2);  

$res = $query->getResult();

return $this->render('FooTransBundle:Default:search.html.twig', array(
'res' => $res));
}
```

And in my twig I have a search.html.twig

```
   <form class="form-horizontal"role="form"name ="search"method="post" action="{{path('foo_trans_search') }}">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="agr"class="col-sm-2 control-label">Trans Type</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text"class="form-control"id="agr"placeholder="Trans type" name ="search">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="trad"class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text"class="form-control"id="trad"placeholder="Name" name ="search1">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="send"class="col-sm-2 control-label">Send Date:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text"class="form-control"id="send"placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"name ="search2">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit"class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
 </div>
  </form>
```

What I want is to search data from database by filling out the three input fields, two input fields and or even only one of the three input fields. But still it will return the searched data.

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in two step your app should work :

First : get restult

```
 $res =  $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Two : browse res in your view

```
{%for result in res %}

   {{ result.name }}

{%endfor%}
```

you can do it better by use a symfony form.

Comment: I was able to do that already. But my problem is how can I will be able to search without filling all of the inputs fields. Example, I will only fill up the input field for Trans type and the other two I will leave it blank but still my search function will try to find something based on the field that I have filled something. Thanks.

Comment: @user3793105 try using % `setParameter('data','%'.$data."%"); ` when your input is empty the filter if %% so it's select all.

Comment: Yes it's working fine but I have another problem. Before putting anything it will already display all the data from my database.           ->setParameter('data','%'.$data."%")
   ->setParameter('data1', '%'.$data1."%")
   ->setParameter('data2','%'.$data2."%"); when I do these in my controller.